# Are all ports open between VMs in an Azure Subnet by default

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, port, subnet

By default, are all the ports between VMs in a given Azure Subnet open ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Azure virtual network, there are few security rules which comes by default. The [Default security rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview#default-security-rules) explains default rules in each network security group on Azure.

Comment: So based on the rule "AllowVNetInBound", the answer to my question would be - yes. Please confirm

Comment: That's correct, Anand. Sorry, I had to be very clear in the answer.